# Number of Gauss chords (except not :-)

Tags: graph-theory

Amusingly, it's quite similar and also related to knot theory.
Draw (and connect in black) 2n points on a circle and connect (in another color) them pairwise by straight lines inside the circle. Crossings are allowed. Do NOT connect points that are direct neighbors or have the same neighbor, because the graph would be reducible as 3n-j symbol. Graphs count as equivalent under rotation and mirroring, but coloring must stay the same.
2n=4: 0 graphs, 6: 1 graphs, 8: 3 graphs...is the general formula known? (Stoimenow, Discrete Mathematics 218(1-3):209-233, gives the number of chord diagrams, maybe one can simply subtract the "forbidden"?)

Comment: So, these are hamiltonian cubic graphs with no triangles.

Comment: For 2n=4, what's wrong with the graph with no edges?

Comment: @GjergjiZaimi, the question says you're supposed to connect various pairs of vertices, so "no edges" won't do.

Comment: The question seems to require edges only between vertices of distance $\geq 3$ on the circle.

Comment: @GjergjiZaimi I think the question only allows edges between vertices at distance at least 3, but requires each vertex to be trivalent. Or at least that is my understanding.

Comment: @Gerry: 3n-j Yutsis graphs with one special Hamiltonian path (with different spin), yes. Some additional background: The "unblack" lines are the adjoint, and all graphs containing also nodes of pure adjoint can be rewritten by IHX rule to give these type...unless you get TWO black circles that way. But that's a different question :-)